# Maximum number of connections per host with twisted.web.client.Agent

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code which creates an HTTPConnectionPool using TwistedMatrix Python framework, and an Agent for HTTP requests:

```
    self.pool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor, persistent=True)
    self.pool.retryAutomatically = False
    self.pool.maxPersistentPerHost = 1
    self.agent = Agent(reactor, pool=self.pool)
```

then I create requests to connect to a local server:

```
    d = self.agent.request(
        "GET",
         url,
         Headers({"Host": ["localhost:8333"]}),
         None)
```

The problem is: the local server sometimes behaves incorrectly when multiple simultaneous requests are made, so I would like to limit the number of simultaneous requests to 1.

The additional requests should be queued until the pending request completes.

I've tried with `self.pool.maxPersistentPerHost = 1` but it doesn't work.

Does twisted.web.client.Agent with HTTPConnectionPool support limiting the maximum number of connections per host, or do I have to implement a request FIFO queue myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason setting `maxPersistentPerHost` to `1` didn't help is that `maxPersistentPerHost` is for controlling the maximum number of persistent connections to **cache** per host.  It does not prevent additional connections from being opened in order to service new requests, it will only cause them to be closed immediately after a response is received, if the maximum number of cached connections has already been reached.

You can enforce serialization in a number of ways.  One way to have a "FIFO queue" is with `twisted.internet.defer.DeferredLock`.  Use it together with `Agent` like this:

```
lock = DeferredLock()
d1 = lock.run(agent.request, url, ...)
d2 = lock.run(agent.request, url, ...)
```

The second request will not run until after the first as completed.