# With treq/twisted, requests received out of order

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, twisted

I am new to Twisted and started using treq because of its similarity to Requests (very easy to use basic authentication etc). I have an HTTPConnectionPool with maxPersistentPerHost=1 and persistence=True, I send 4 requests in a row to a host: treq.put(1), treq.get(1), treq.put(2) and treq.get(1). However the apache server running on the host receives the requests out of order (checked /var/log/apache2/access.log). Using netstat I saw 4 connections to the host, I was expecting only 1 connection and all requests to go over the same connection in order. Any idea on what I am doing wrong or missing?

Thanks!
Reshad.

Comment: Ran into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854855/maximum-number-of-connections-per-host-with-twisted-web-client-agent. DeferredLock() works.