# How to limit the download rate in Twisted http client?

Tags: twisted

Is there a way to limit the download rate in Twisted http client? If not, What's the easiest way to implement such a client in Twisted?

Answer (score 4):

Flow control in Twisted is most commonly achieved using `IProducer.pauseProducing` and `IProducer.resumeProducing`.

You need to measure throughput coming from a producer yourself and call `pauseProducing` and `resumeProducing` at the appropriate times to limit bandwidth usage to the level you're seeking.

When you use `IResponse.deliverBody` the protocol you supply will be attached to an object that provides `IProducer`.  When you pause and resume that object, you are controlling the rate at which the response body is read from the network.

So, for example:

```
class SlowDownloader(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, reactor):
        self.reactor = reactor

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Received', len(data), 'bytes'
        self.transport.pauseProducing()
        # Delay further reading so that the download proceeds at
        # 1kB/sec at the fastest.
        delay = len(data) / 1024.0
        self.reactor.callLater(delay, self.transport.resumeProducing)

requesting = agent.request(...)
def requested(response):
    response.deliverBody(SlowDownloader())
requesting.addCallback(requested)
```

This isn't a particularly great rate-limiting implementation.  It may go slower than you intend if there is a long delay between `resumeProducing` being called and the next `dataReceived` call.  Fixing that is just a matter of doing some more time-based math though.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this poster was having [a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854855/maximum-number-of-connections-per-host-with-twisted-web-client-agent), and the accepted wisdom was that controlling the rate should be done by running `agent.request` sequentially on your own with a help of lock. HTH.

Comment: "maximum number of concurrent connections" is different than "maximum bandwidth".  On the other hand, the OP was not entirely clear...

Comment: Yes definitely they are different, and the OPs question is equivocal. The gist of the answer is manual control over the issued `agent.request`, but you are right the issues shouldn't be called very similar.